Is there a way to see machines you've put Sommersloops in?
With the right research you can use the sloops to have an effect on a machine. I don't remember where all I've done this though, and I've built a lot of machines that are potentially ones I've used sloops on. If there's not a way to find the machines it'll probably be easier to go hunt up more then try and find the machines because of this.

I believe they make a sound, but other than that I'm not aware of any way to track which machines have them.

Oh, manufacturer's exhaust is a different color ... still would be lovely if I could see it on the map or something.

I think you can interact with the machine to see what's been inserted at the bottom three grey blocks where you'd overclock, but interacting with every machine would be a nightmare! Can you scan for them and detect them in machines perhaps?

@Neon1024 You can not scan for them, and while the exhaust color does change, that doesn't help if the machine is turned off. I may have to build a "Sloopflag" blueprint that I can set down next to machines that use them unless there is a way.

How do you feel about 3rd party tools? You can do this via the https://satisfactory-calculator.com!
This site lets you upload a save file, which will then render your save, including individual belts, etc.
On the right side of the menu, there is the "Buildings List" button

Within this menu, you can view stats for the individual machines you have: 
...and pressing the rightmost button will take you directly to where that machine is located within the map of your factory!
Alternatively!
If you're stuck on an in-game only option, you might consider dragging the deconstruct tool around your factory -- just highlighting the factory buildings will show what items you'll get back when dismantling them -- and that includes Somersloops.
As long as you're diligent and thorough, you can rapidly figure out what machines have somersloops, even if they're not active, and at a distance! (Just be careful to not actually complete the dismantle)

This may narrow it down, but I think the OP wants to know if there is a way to get a physical location of what machines contain a sloop

The right-most button on that screen will take you (on the interactive map) to where the machine is located, actually! (The location icon inside of a magnifying glass)

I've accepted this answer, but I'd suggest adding a note that you can also see fairly quickly in your local area by pressing F to dismantle and then mousing over potential machines. The list of resources will include any sloops in the machine you are potentially dismantling.

Additional note: You can dismantle from farther away when you're flying whether that's due to Jetpack, Hoverpack or Fly Mode -

And parachute!!
